# Suppose $a$ and $b$ are integers so that not both $a$ and $b$ are zeroes. Prove that not both $3a+2b$ and $5a+3b$ are zeroes

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, divisibility

The is from an introduction discrete mathematics course.

Suppose $a$ and $b$ are integers so that not both a and b are zeroes. Prove that not both $3a+2b$ and $5a+3b$ are zeroes and that $gcd(3a+2b, 5a+3b)$ = $gcd(a,b)$.

I understand how to prove that $gcd(3a+2b, 5a+3b)$ = $gcd(a,b)$ but not sure how to prove the initial part: "Suppose $a$ and $b$ are integers so that not both $a$ and $b$ are zeroes. Prove that not both $3a+2b$ and $5a+3b$ are zeroes."

How do I go about proving the initial statement?

Comment: $$\begin{pmatrix}3 & 2 \\ 5 & 3\end{pmatrix}$$ has determinant $-1$, hence it is an invertible matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that both $3a+2b$ and $5a + 3b$ are equal to zero.

Then we get that $15a + 10b = 15a + 9b \implies b = 0$. Therefore we must have that $a \not = 0$. Hence we have that $3a + 2b = 3a \not = 0$. Therefore we obtain a contradiction, so at least one of $3a+2b$ and $5a+3b$ isn't zero.

Comment: I followed you until this statement. Can you elaborate on what is meant here: 3a+2b=3a≠0

Comment: @SajSeesSound We have that $b=0$, so $3a + 2b = 3a + 2\cdot 0 = 3a \not = 0$, as we must have $a \not = 0$.

Comment: Is it logically correct to prove a portion of a statement by contradiction and the rest as a direct proof (as is being done in this case based on your answer)?

Comment: @SajSeesSound Why not? BTW my proof is just contradiction. I mean we get that one of the varaibles is zero and we use this fact to get a contradiction. Another way to prove it is to notice that $9a + 6b = 10a + 9b \implies a=0$, but we know that $b=0$, so this violates the initial condition.

Comment: I dont understand how you proved it in your second example. Why are you assuming that b=0 (unless you consider the work you did in the first example)?

Comment: @SajSeesSound Multiply the first equation by $3$, the second one by $2$ and subtract them to get that $a=0$. Also now multiply the first by $5$, the second one by $3$ to get that $b=0$. But this is impossible, as the condition says  at least one of $a$ and $b$ is different than $0$.

Comment: So the second example was basically unnecessary, since it is an AND statement and you only need to contradict one part of it?

Comment: Is there a way to incorporate the 'Suppose a and b are integers so that not both a and b are zeroes' or was it just included in the initial question for clarity?

Comment: @SajSeesSound You can just write that at the begining of the proof, by I think it's already understandable from the context of the question.